Problem with calling Python module from C# code via Python.Net
I am trying to integrate C# and Python codes by calling Python.Net from C# code (Net6.0 Visual Studio 2022, Windows10 platform). I added pythonnet package from Nuggets to my project, identified the path to my python311.dll, and try to call my Python module in the following way (below is a toy model showing the problem):
public static void RunScript(string script)
{
    Runtime.PythonDLL = @"C:\Users\UserName\anaconda3\python311.dll";
    PythonEngine.Initialize();
    using (Py.GIL())
    {
        var pScr = Py.Import(script);
        var res = pScr.InvokeMethod("hello_python");    
    }
}

// Main Method
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    RunScript("hello");
}


Here “hello_python.py” is some toy Python file just printing something.
When I try to run the above code, the line “PythonEngine.Initialize();” throws an exception “Win32Exception: The specified module could not be found.”
Any idea what may cause it? Python311.dll is most definitely there, pythonnet is also installed. Thank you!
I tried different Python libraries, and CPU configurations at my project settings, but that seems to be irrelevant.

this appears to be more of a c# question that a python question.
